# AWS Enterprise Account - IAM Settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

When I login to my enterprise aws account , I see something like the below. Does this mean that there is a single account id and I am created as a user within some group within the account? I see "assumed-role" mentioned in account name , wasn't quite sure what it means.

```
Account Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
Account Name: assumed-role/XXXXX_Dev_Developer/<employee id>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are a single IAM user under the enterprise account. The assumed role controls what you can do within the scope of that account, for instance restricted read from an S3 bucket or write into one.

These roles are assigned by your account administrator, typically someone in your organization.

Comment: Thanks Timir , does it mean it’s a single account with multiple users under it ? I thought assumed role is used for restricting activities that one account can perform on another

Comment: The usual use case is RBAC within the account, though you might also setup roles for privileges across accounts. I haven't dealt with the latter, and assume you would have to be an administrator of both accounts to do so.